is it possible to train NER model on en_core_web_lg without static_vectors?
I am trying to train an NER model with custom tokenization. it works fine with the en_core_web_sm model, but I am trying to increase accuracy so I am now trying with en_core_web_lg. no matter what I seem to do to disable static vectors, it always ends up complaining:
RuntimeError: [E896] There was an error using the static vectors. Ensure that the vectors of the vocab are properly initialized, or set 'include_static_vectors' to False
I have decided against using static vectors as I must use custom tokenization, and as I am new I decided that simply not using it would be better. is this wrong?
this is the code I am using for the large model:
def train_model(train_data, output_dir, n_iter=50):
    # Enable GPU
    spacy.require_gpu()
    
    # Load the pre-trained model including tok2vec, but excluding vectors
    nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg", exclude=["vectors"])
    
    # Set custom tokenizer
    nlp.tokenizer = custom_tokenizer(nlp)
    
    # Ensure no component is using static vectors
    for component in nlp.pipe_names:
        if hasattr(nlp.get_pipe(component), "include_static_vectors"):
            nlp.get_pipe(component).include_static_vectors = False
    
    # Check if the NER pipe exists, if not add it
    if "ner" not in nlp.pipe_names:
        ner = nlp.add_pipe("ner", last=True)
    else:
        ner = nlp.get_pipe("ner")
    
    # Add labels to the NER model
    for example in train_data:
        for ent in example.reference.ents:
            ner.add_label(ent.label_)
    
    # Create an optimizer with the correct components
    optimizer = nlp.create_optimizer()

    for i in range(n_iter):
        random.shuffle(train_data)
        losses = {}
        batches = minibatch(train_data, size=compounding(4.0, 32.0, 1.001))
        for batch in batches:
            nlp.update(batch, drop=0.5, losses=losses, sgd=optimizer)
        print(f"Iteration {i + 1}/{n_iter}: Losses {losses}")
    
    # Save the model to the output directory
    if output_dir is not None:
        nlp.to_disk(output_dir)
        print(f"Saved model to {output_dir}")

it results in the previously mentioned runtime error
